# Dell Inspiron 5558, Window 8.1 pro

Tags: synaptics-touchpad

My laptop is Dell Inspiron 5558 series and I am currently using window 8.1 pro version. I'd like to ask "how I enable or disable the touch-pad" as it is disturbing by moving the cursor when I am typing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Turning off Synaptics 3 finger gestures on Dell laptop](https://superuser.com/questions/203953/turning-off-synaptics-3-finger-gestures-on-dell-laptop)

Answer (score 0):

Make certain you have a working mouse attached and then follow this Dell Link with an accepted solution.

https://www.dell.com/community/Laptops-General-Read-Only/Disable-touchpad/td-p/4657777

> 1. Right click the Start's button at the bottom left hand of the page
> 2. Click Device Manager
> 3. Look for "Mice and other pointed things"
> 4. Right click Dell Touchpad. You should see the Disable option